During Edo period Japan, was there any circumstance where a Western person was able to go outside of Dejima?
I know that during the Edo period Westerners (specifically the Dutch) were confined in Dejima due to Japan's isolationist policy. But as I was looking into the time period, it seems to me that there were a few people who were able to travel outside of Dejima toward the 19th century (Ranald McDonald and Mercator Cooper). So I'm curious if there were any more instances when a Western person was able to travel in Japan without being confined to Dejima, and if this was something that could theoretically be done in that time period.
I'm unable to find any good source about life of Westerners in the Edo Period. The sources that I found all say the same thing about Japan closing down to foreigners. This source focuses mostly on the trading. This source says that the isolationist policy was actually not that strict and by-the-book and the government would only crack down on cases that proved to be problematic to the national security. This one further makes me curious if the isolationist policy was actually as strict as it is often described and could leave leeway for people to move around.

I am not a Japan expert, and can't cite sources (hence comment), but my memory is that most edicts were performative; they served to communicate the government's will/policy. As is not uncommon among autocracy's the principle agent problem constrains enforcement.  If my memory is correct, then quiet circumvention of the policy would not be a problem, so long as it dd not cause the administration to lose face.

As the Wikipedia article about Dejima mentions, the Dutch were not confined their until 1640, so that's over 30 years of the early Edo period that they were trading elsewhere (mainly Hirado).

It also mentions that the Dutch representative had to go to Edo to pay annual tribute to the Shogun. Citation is needed but here is an image that supposedly shows a large enterage en route from 1727.

Looking a little further I see books by Goodman (2000) and Clulow (2013) all about the Dutch presence in Japan. The first of these has a whole chapter about the tributary missions to Edo.
